# "Hessian" differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In my homework, I'm given the following problem:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function. For an $\alpha \geq 2$, let: $$f(\lambda x) = \lambda^a f(x)$$
>
> for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda > 0.$
>
> Show that
>
> $$
> \sum_{i,k=1}^{n}(\partial_i \partial_k f)(x) x_i x_k = \alpha(\alpha - 1)f(x)
> $$
>
> holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda > 0.$

I'm not sure where to start here. I've tried setting $n = 2$, just to be able to understand what the sum expresses, but I'm not sure if I know any rules that I could apply here to simplify this.

Thematically, we haven't covered PDEs yet, and it appears that all I need for solving this would be differential calculus.

Could someone please walk me through this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of the equation $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^{a}f(x)$ in $\lambda$ to obtain:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}(\partial_{i}f)(\lambda x) = a\lambda^{a-1}f(x)
\end{equation}

Setting $\lambda = 1$ yields $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}(\partial_{i}f)(x) = af(x)$, known as Euler's identity.

Differentiating the equation displayed above in $\lambda$ again, and setting $\lambda = 1$ in the result yields the desired relation.

One says that $f$ has homogeneity $a$. Taking derivatives reduces homogeneity by one. This can be remembered as follows. The variables $x_{i}$ have homogeneity $1$, so the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ have homogeneity $-1$.